# how can I show NSDate type value to UILabel?

Tags: swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to show current server time if the user type any site name.
And time should keep going every second.

I could get specific server time using Alamofire.

```
if let headers = result?.allHeaderFields {
    if let date = headers["Date"] as? String {
        let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"
        formatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
        currentTime.text = formatter.dateFromString(date)
    }
}
```

in constant date , there is a value `"Sun, 20 Mar 2016 13:31:08 GMT"` type of `String`.

I'm trying to change this value to `NSDate` type to change date format and locale.

It gives an error

> Can not assign value of type 'NSDate' to type 'String'.

How can I put `NSDate` type to `currentTime.text`?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `NSDateFormatter` to convert date from `String` to `NSDate`, so you need another `NSDateFormatter` to convert date from `NSDate` back to `String` using new date format.